# The following filterBy function returns an empty array regardless of the filter key

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm creating a `filterBy` function that filters by a `filterKey`:

```
filterBy (data, filterKey) {
  data = data.filter(function (row) {
    return Object.keys(row).some(function (key) {
      return String(row[key]).toLowerCase().indexOf(filterKey) > -1
    })
  })
  console.log(data)
  return data
}
```

`data` looks like: `[ { name: 'Alex', createdAt: '' }, { ... } ]`

`filter` looks like: `A` (a String).

However, `console` logs an empty array no matter what the value of `filter` is: `[]`

What's wrong with my filter function?

**EDIT:** I think I found the problem. How to modify the function so it searches by `name`?

Comment: Are you searching by name only or any other keys also?

Comment: Try with "a" ...

Comment: Add `filterKey = filterKey.toLowerCase();` at the begining of the function. (You're lowercasing the values but not lowercasing the `filterKey`: `'a' !== 'A'`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify the key you want to look for:

```
filterBy (data, key, filterKey) {
    filterKey = filterKey.toLowerCase();                            // first make filterKey lowercased
    return data.filter(function (row) {                             // filter out all objects (rows) that ...
      return String(row[key]).toLowerCase().indexOf(filterKey);     // ... have their value of the key 'key' (lowercased) contains the filterKey (lowercased)
    });
}
```

then you can use it like this (for example):

```
var newArray = filterBy(oldArray, "name", "A");
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `some` function is using `toLowerCase`, but the filter you've used as an example is `A` (uppercase A). If you change the filter to `a` you'll get a result.

Basically, you're supplying an uppercase filter, but only searching for lowercase letters.

```js
var filterBy = function(data, filterKey) {
  var data = data.filter(function(row) {
      return Object.keys(row).some(function(key) {
          return String(row[key]).toLowerCase().indexOf(filterKey) > -1
      })
  })
  console.log(data)
  return data
}

var data = [{
  name: 'Alex',
  createdAt: ''
}, {
  name: 'Brett',
  createdAt: ''
}];

filterBy(data, 'a');
```

Answer (score 1):

To search by name only, you can do this

```
var filterBy =function(data, filterKey) {
  data = data.filter(function (row) {
     return row["name"].toLowerCase().indexOf(filterKey) > -1;
  })
  console.log(data)
  return data
};
var data = [ { name: 'Alex', createdAt: '' }, { name: 'TT', createdAt: '' }, ];
console.log(filterBy(data,"a"));
```